# Unknown error in 8 bit carry-select adder

Tags: vhdl

So I have to make a 8 bit carry select adder for my lab. I looked on wikipedia where I found a diagram for a carry-select adder of n-bits and created what I think should be correct but when I run the simulation I get an incorrect answer. I am attaching my vhdl code if anyone can tell me what is wrong to correctly model a 8 bit carry select adder I would appreciate it.

```
entity CarrySelect is
port(   a : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      b : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
    s : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
      co : out std_logic;
      ci : in std_logic

    );
end CarrySelect;

architecture behav of CarrySelect is

component multiplexer2 is
port (
  a : in std_logic;
  b : in std_logic;
  s : in std_logic;
  y : out std_logic
 );
end component;

component RCA4 is --add RCA4 component for use by CS adder
port (ci: in std_logic;
a, b: in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
s: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
co: out std_logic
);
end component;

signal t0,t1,c0,c1 : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); --temp signals for    passing from RCAs to muxes
signal co1 : std_logic;
begin

--for carry 0
RCA0 : RCA4 port map('0', a(3 downto 0), b(3 downto 0), t0(3 downto 0), c0(0));
RCA2 : RCA4 port map('0', a(7 downto 4), b(7 downto 4), t0(7 downto 4), c0(1));

--for carry 1
RCA1 : RCA4 port map('1', a(3 downto 0), b(3 downto 0), t1(3 downto 0), c1(0));
RCA3 : RCA4 port map('1', a(7 downto 4), b(7 downto 4), t1(7 downto 4), c1(1));

--mux for carry
MUX0 : multiplexer2 port map(c0(0),c1(0),ci,co1);
MUX9 : multiplexer2 port map(c0(1),c1(1),co1,co);
--muxes for sum
MUX1 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(0),t1(0),ci,s(0));
MUX2 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(1),t1(1),ci,s(1));
MUX3 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(2),t1(2),ci,s(2));
MUX4 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(3),t1(3),ci,s(3));
MUX5 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(4),t1(4),co1,s(4));
MUX6 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(5),t1(5),co1,s(5));
MUX7 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(6),t1(6),co1,s(6));
MUX8 : multiplexer2 port map(t0(7),t1(7),co1,s(7));

end architecture behav;
```

Comment: [rtl diagram](http://imgur.com/X8k3FyC)

Comment: So, we have an unknown testbench running unknown tests on an entity that uses unknown components, giving answers that are incorrect in unknown ways. Hmmm, I don't know. Time to start debugging. Examine the internal signal values, tracing forwards from what you DO know - the input signals are as expected, the outputs of this component are as expected, step by step until you get to unexpected results. THEN find out why and fix it.

Comment: Lacking a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and no identification of the stimuli and result constituting an incorrect answer I wrote a multiplexer2 component and found a modified something for an RCA4. With a quick and dirty testbench the connectivity expresses in CarrySelect appears correct. The problem lies either in one of your two components or the testbench.

Comment: @C_Cleveland I know the question is very old. The purpose and point of SO is to carry the knowledge to the rest of people that may search for the same question. In my case, I would like to see the diagram. But it says 404.
Also, what solved your case? MaryTheFairy's answer is not that clear for me and you didn't include your components...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at this code(without the code for components and any test benches) I think I spotted something that may be wrong.
When you use the RCA4 component to create a bigger RCA with 0 as carry in you compose 2 RCA4, RCA2 (in the port map) needs to have the carry our from RCA0 as carry in and not 0. 
Try changing that,I hope I helped.